# xslt 1.0 How to convert &lt; into less than in words

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML

```
    <node>
    <operator>&lt;</operator>
<value>2</value>
    </node>
    <node>
    <operator>&gt;</operator>
<value>1.1</value>
    </node>.....
```

I need to transform this as follows
Lessthan 2
Greaterthan 1.1

I tried with the below code but it does not work as expected.

Is there any suggestions?

```
<xsl:variable name="lt">
 <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="ConditionalDoseOperator">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="operator=$lt">
    <xsl:value-of select="Lessthan" />
    </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>

 </xsl:variable>                                      

<xsl:value-of select="$ConditionalDoseOperator" />
```

I am expecting to see Lessthan in words but it is blank content.

Comment: Your code doesn't show the context. Is the value of the element "operator" available at this point? Have you tried to output the plain value here to be sure?

Comment: @Andreas, yes I have a foreach loop for "Node". This loop encloses the above code.

Comment: Please show a complete input XML, and a complete stylesheet: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest doing it the simple way:

```
<xsl:for-each select="node">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="operator='&lt;'">less than</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="operator='&gt;'">greater than</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="operator"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```